# Attempt to assign property "job_title" on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backend, laravel-8

I'm making a CRUD App, Everything is working fine except Updation. I want to update data in my MySQL table.
Controller code:

```
function postupdate(Request $req)
{
    $post_id=$req->get('post_id');
    dd($post_id); //data is pass from blade file,the answer is correct
    $var = post::find($post_id);
    dd($var); // it return "null"
    $var->job_title=$req->input('job_title');
    $var->job_venue=$req->input('job_venue');
    $var->job_address=$req->input('job_address');
    $var->job_salary=$req->input('job_salary');
    $var->job_category=$req->input('job_category');
    $var->job_description=$req->input('job_description');
    $var->job_benefit=$req->input('job_benefit');
    $var->job_highlight=$req->input('job_highlight');
    $var->job_requirement=$req->input('job_requirement');
    $var->update();
    return redirect('searchpost')->with('successMsg','Job Post Successfully !');
}
```

Blade file

```
<div class="container2">
@foreach(Session::get('result') as $detaa)
<input type="hidden" class="text" placeholder="Company's ID" value="{{ $detaa->id}}"name="id" id="id">
    <img class="background_img" src="/nobackground.jfif" id="background"/>
@if($detaa->company_logo)
        <img src="{{$detaa->company_logo}}" name="image" class="emp_pic" id="image"><h2 style="padding-left:23%;margin-top:-9%;" class="name">{{$detaa->company_name}}<br><br></h2>
@else
    <img class="emp_pic" src="/nologo.png" name="image"id="image"/>
@endif
@endforeach
<br>
@foreach($result as $detaa)
<form action='/postupdate' method='post'enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
<input type="hidden" class="text" placeholder="Post's ID" value="{{ $detaa->post_id}}" name="post_id" id="post_id" required readonly>
    <table>
<tr> 
<th>Job title:</th>
<th><input type="text" class="text" placeholder="Job Title" name="job_title" value="{{ $detaa->job_title}}" id="job_title" required></th>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Venue:</th>
<th><input type="text" class="text"placeholder ="Working Place"  name="job_venue" value="{{ $detaa->job_venue}}" id="job_venue" required></input>
</tr>
```

Since the $var there return "null", so it shows the error "Attempt to assign property "job_title" on null". I had no idea where i did wrong.

Comment: your error says it ***Attempt to assign property "job_title" on null***. check the payload

Comment: So the `$var = post::find($post_id);` returns null it means that the `$post_id` not exists in the database or tyr to do it like so `$var = Post::find($post_id);` with `P` not `p` and do not forget the import

Comment: i did try to change to $var = Post::find($post_id); but it still didn't work.

Comment: I had solved the problem and this is my code. Thank you, guys.

function postupdate(Request $req, $post_id)
{
            if($req->session()->has('result')){
                $result=session('result.0.id');
                $var = post::where('post_id', '=', $req->post_id)->where('id','=',$result)->first();

//others same as above
                }

    }